# ackでShift-JISのテキストを検索対象にする

Tags: command-line

`ack`でShift-JISのテキストファイルを検索したかったのですが
以下のようにデフォルトではShift-JISのファイルは検索対象にならないようです。

```
% echo '日本語' > foo.txt
% ack 日本語
foo.txt
1:日本語
% echo '日本語' | iconv -t SJIS > foo.txt
% ack 日本語
%
```

オプションをつければ可能なのだと思うのですが、
調べてみても方法がわかりませんでした。

Macにて以下のバージョンの`ack`を使っています。

```
ack --version
ack 2.18
Running under Perl 5.18.2 at /usr/bin/perl
```

どうすればShiftJISのテキストを`ack`で検索できますか？

Comment: ackのかわりに、ripgrepやptを使うのが良さそうです。参考: https://blog.3qe.us/entry/2017/08/08/010329

Comment: まぁ、無理矢理ですけど、`ack "$(echo '日本語' | iconv -t SJIS | sed 's/{/\\{/g')" foo.txt | iconv -f SJIS -t UTF-8` とすればできますが、、、検索対象のファイルのエンコーディングを UTF-8 に変換して ack で処理する方が現実的ではないかと思います。